# php create array with key by html input

Tags: php, arrays, input

am trying to create array with key by using html input 
here's my html input

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name[][you]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[][he]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[][she]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[][you]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[][he]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[][she]" value="" />
<button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
```

my outbut is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [you] => jhon ) [1] => Array ( [he] => joy ) [2] => Array ( [she] => sarah ) [3] => Array ( [you] => samm ) [4] => Array ( [he] => petter ) [5] => Array ( [she] => susan ) )
```

but i want the array to be like this

```
Array( [0]=> array ( [you] => jhon [he] => joy [she] => sarah )[1]=> array ( [you] => pitter [he] => tom [she] => suszan ) )
```

is there away to do that

Comment: Why don't you write the exact numbers in the brackets - `<input type="text" name="name[0][you]" value="" />` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this ==>

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name[0][you]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[0][he]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[0][she]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[1][you]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[1][he]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name[1][she]" value="" />
<button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
```

> OR

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php $n = 2; // how many interval you want
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>][you]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>][he]" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $i; ?>][she]" value="" />

<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: yes just like that but without set key number in the input

Comment: @MounerMostafa then try the 2nd dynamic solution given by me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output an array with two children then set the keys manually, name[0] for the first three inputs and name[1] for the last three.

Comment: so there's no way to do this without using key number in the input ?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you write `name="[][key]"` php increment automatic the key.
if you write syntax like `[]` php increment the index of array.

Small explation
For example:
If you write an array like this

```
$array[] = "msg1";
$array[] = "msg2";
$array[] = "msg3";
```

`$array` length will be 2 (3 elements because it starts from 0) and it is same as

```
$array[0] = "msg1";
$array[1] = "msg2";
$array[2] = "msg3";
```

This is `different` from above

```
$array[0] = "msg1";
$array[1] = "msg2";
$array[1] = "msg3";
```

This array will have only 1 length (2 elements only)

Solution of your question is :

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name[0][you]" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name[0][he]" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name[0][she]" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name[1][you]" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name[1][he]" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name[1][she]" value="" />
  <button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
```